# Chain functions unknown number of times

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am animating an element's top/left css values via an unknown number of steps. I'm using the following code to store the required css values for each step of the animation:

```
paths = [{ left:-300 }, { top:-161 }, { left:-402 }];
```

I can then run the animation via:

```
$element.animate(paths[0]).animate(paths[1]).animate(paths[2]);
```

so that each animation starts when the previous one finishes: this works fine. However, what if I wanted to increase the number of steps from 3 (left-top-left) to 6? Or 50? How can I chain functions an unknown number of times?

Comment: Are you sure that it works fine? At the end of animation the `complete` handler is called. So it should be something like `$element.animate(paths[0], function() { $element.animate(paths[1], ...) });`. Chaining should start all the animations at one time.

Comment: @VisioN Yup, chaining like this works the same way as if using a callback. See http://api.jquery.com/animate/#example-2

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
$element.animate(paths.shift(), function next() {
    $(this).animate(paths.shift(), paths.length && next);
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/Xsz8w/2/

`paths.length && next` is needed to prevent infinite callback invocation.

Answer (score 1):

Have a recursive function instead, which calls itself until the last element of the paths array.

```
var paths = [{ left:-300 }, { top:-161 }, { left:-402 }];

(function animateNext(i){

  $element.animate(paths[i],function(){

    //on animation complete, check if the next path exists
    if(paths[++i]){

      // if so, let's animate using the next path
      animateNext(i);
    }
  });

//start from index 0
}(0));
```

Answer (score 1):

```
var paths = [{ left: -300 }, { top: -161 }, { left: -402 }];

(function animateElement(index) {
    if (paths[index] == null) return;
    $element.animate(paths[index], function () {
        animateElement(index++);
    });
})(0);
```

Answer (score 0):

You could loop each of the items and use the `success` function to call the next.

You could also potentially add an `interval` to your JSON and use `animate` and `delay` in tandem.

Answer (score -1):

I don't have any experience with jQuery, so I'm going to assume that you need the output from `animate(a)` to call the next one.

```
var e = $element;
for (var i = 0; i < paths.length; i++) {
    e = e.animate(paths[i]);
}
```