# Chain functions based on array values

Tags: javascript, arrays, recursion, mapreduce

I have an array of **arbitrary length** containing something like:

```
const arr = [{key: 345}, {key: 786}, {key: 980}];
```

I want to return a function that returns a promise chain using the array.

```
function getCallback(arr) {
  return function(builder) {
    return builder
     .where(arr[0].key)
     .where(arr[1].key)
     .where(arr[2].key)
  }
}
```

Not sure how to achieve this with an array of arbitrary length. I looked at a [recursive solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15337560/chain-functions-unknown-number-of-times) but was not able to fit it in this use case.

Comment: what should be the result of it?

Comment: the array should be used to construct a chain of method calls.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You don't have to chain the function calls the way you do it in your sample code right now. Instead, call them separately in a loop:

```js
const arr = [{key: 345}, {key: 786}, {key: 980}];

function getCallback(arr) {
  return function(builder) {
    arr.forEach(function(item) {
      builder = builder.where(item.key);
    });
    return builder;
  }
}
                
var MockBuilder = function() {}
MockBuilder.prototype.where = function(key) {
  console.log(key);
  return this;
};
    
var callback = getCallback(arr);
callback(new MockBuilder());
```

Comment: how do you know what he asked

Comment: Magnifique! +1 for simplicity!

Comment: What you are doing is essentially a reduce so we could also use a reducer instead of looping: `arr.reduce((memo, item) => memo.where(item.key)), builder)`